# I invite you to my daughter's wedding with Peter

Tags: grammaticality, sentence

Is the sentence grammatically correct to convey that Peter is the groom, or does it seem to confuse whether Peter is an invitee or groom ?

Comment: It's confusing...

Comment: It is a trifle ambiguous, I must say! If Peter is the groom, why not say "I invite you to my daughter's wedding TO Peter". At least that would be the British way of saying it (assuming you were not sending a printed invitation). In the UK we get married "to someone", not "with someone". Similarly we speak "to people" not "with people".

Comment: For a wedding invitation, it is wrong.

Comment: https://www.brides.com/story/guide-to-wedding-invitation-wording

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convey that Peter is the groom, you should use *to*.

> I invite you to my daughter’s wedding *to* Peter.

Answer (score 0):

English does not use the conjunction "with" when people marry each other. It uses "to".

> Jane got married **with** Peter:WRONG
>
> Jane got married **to** Peter:RIGHT

Using "with" makes the reader think it means something else, that you are invited to bring another guest, Peter, **with** you.

Substituting "to" for "with" makes it clear.

Comment: This is just blatantly wrong. The verb _marry_ licenses prepositional phrase complements headed by both _to_ and _with_. Also, _with_ is in no way a conjunction as it cannot join finite clauses together; it is a preposition.

Comment: Do you have a reference for that? "With" is a common mistake, but native speakers would not use it. Unless this is a dialect thing.

Comment: Shakespeare _He hath my good will, and none but he, to marry with Nan Page_

Comment: A Fictional History of the United States, T Cooper & A  Mansbach _I do not even attempt to make it clear I am a member of something besides the Narragansett tribe, who have begun to marry with our children._

Comment: The Student's Cabinet Library of Useful Tracts _Among the Saxons, says Adam of Bremen, it is commanded, that no unequal marriages be contracted — that noble marry with noble, freeman with freewoman, freedman with freedwoman, slave with slave_

Comment: It might not be common, but it's well established. There are many more examples of educated native speakers using _with_ and _marry_ together in order to talk about joining people in matrimony.

Answer (score -1):

Note: I'm leaving aside here the use of preposition *with* or *to*; my answer is purely based on the structure of the sentence, which is the focus of the OP's question.

While technically ambiguous, most people would assume that Peter was the groom.

If you want to express that Peter was another guest included in your invitation, you would say

> I invite you and Peter to my daughter's wedding.
>
> You and Peter are invited to my daughter's wedding.
>
> You are invited to my daughter's wedding, as is Peter.

The reason why Peter would be seen as the groom is the distance between *you* and *Peter* in the original sentence. Because the reason for the invitation comes between the two words, it would be odd if *you with Peter* was a single phrase.

So syntactically is is possible, but pragmatically it would not be ambiguous.